# EF 6 Code First Migration - Controlling the sequence in which Migration scripts execute and DB schema gets created

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, database-schema, entity-framework-migrations

This is my first question in SO, though i have been referring to questions posted for quite some time.

I was recently doing a code first migration for an existing database to migrate it to the latest version. My DB initializer was using the default strategy "CreateDatabaseIfNotExists" and I'm using SQL server 2012 express.

The following were the steps used to do the migration:
1. Enabled migrations with the older database v1 and corresponding code version cv1. Generated initial migration script with -IgnoreChanges option. Updated the database with this migration.
2. With the latest code version cv2, used the older database v1. Added migration to generate the actual migration script for the schema changes and updated database

This worked perfectly for an existing database and it got successfully migrated to the latest version.

But for a new database, the database gets created, but seeding was not happening. On debugging, I could notice that the migration scripts are getting executed first even before DB schema was created.

The migration scripts are failing since the tables being migrated have not even been added yet.

Note:
I have turned OFF AutomaticMigrationsEnabled for migrations.

Please note, a similar approach to the above was working fine for the earlier version of EF - 4.3 which i was using.

This is the code in App_Start:

Database.SetInitializer(new DBLayer.Models.MyDBInitializer());
            using (MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext())
            {
                db.Database.Initialize(false);

```
            if (!db.Database.Exists())
            {
                ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();                    
            }

            //Initializing membership APIs
            MembershipInitializer.InstallServices();
```

In the above code,  after db.Database.Initialize, migration scripts are executing where as tables are not yet added and hence error gets thrown.

On disabling migrations and creating a new database, things work fine again.

My questions are:

1. How can you control this sequence for executing migration scripts to first add the tables before executing migration scripts. What am I missing here?
2. When automatic migration is turned OFF which are the migration scripts getting executed first place?

Please advise. Please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: How does the initial migration look like? From your description i suppose it is empty (because of the -ignorechanges switch). How could the migrator update the empty database based on an empty migration.

Comment: Yes agreed its empty, but when you add migration for an existing database, if you don't ignore the current schema, it would try to drop and re-create the whole schema. In this case, the migration would not serve its purpose. Are there any alternatives to "-Ignore changes".

Comment: Have you tried without -Ignorechanges? This should produce a Migration which descripes the current state of your database. Get the script for this Migration, copy the line which inserts the metadata into the MigrationsHistory table and execute that line in ssms.

Comment: Yes scripting migration scripts and copying MigrationHistory works. Which is equivalent to commenting out the code in Up and Down methods of each migration script.

Comment: So by far, the best way of including migrations is a two way approach: one for existing database migration - initial migration only for snapshot and required migrations for newer version, the other for the new database with migration added only for current snapshot. In effect, by keeping two different copies of the migration files for the two versions. Is there any better way out?